# How to write ruby code easier?(I mean in terminal write and then run it)

Tags: ruby, vim

When I write a little ruby code, after a little bit, I always need to create a new terminal tab to ruby it, to see if it's correct.

Are there any ways to do it in one window? Like a vim plugin or some other tool?

Answer (score 5):

The following should work in vim, after you've saved the file:

```
:!ruby %
```

Or even

```
:!%
```

This works under Linux when you have the correct "shebang" as the first line of the ruby file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

For extra fun, you can map this to a key in your ~/.vimrc:

```
map <F8> :!ruby %<CR>
```

Comment: @ciastek, I rolled back the edits you made, as I didn't see what they added.  Feel free to add your own derivative answer.

Comment: `%` gives you filename, `%:p` gives you full path. It allows executing current file even if you don't have `.` in your `PATH`.

`:help filename-modifiers`

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you need an interpreter to see what your code does? If so, check out [irb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell).

Answer (score 1):

The way you should check if your code works is using unit tests, not running it in the console or irb. Indeed, irb is a good solution for small fragment of code or to check for specific statements.

However, there are some solutions to your specific question.
You can write the code in a file, save it and run it from the console.

```
ruby filename.rb
```

If you use TextMate, you can press `⌘ + R` to execute the current code

Comment: Well, he still needs somewhere to run the tests ;-) For small code, using the `if __FILE__ == $0` trick to run the test code ought to be OK, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Do as Simone Carletti said.

And for editing and saving your file suggest you Scite.
http://www.scintilla.org/SciTEDownload.html here you can download it for many different operating systems.
You get syntax highlighting in a very lightweight editor for almost everything (html, ruby, eruby, xml,...).

But you will need to have at least a Window Manager running.

Comment: And of course (in Windows at least) you can F5 and run the script, with output to the, er, output pane.

Comment: see there is another fan of scite ^^

Answer (score 1):

in **~/.vimrc**

```
autocmd FileType ruby imap <F8> <C-o>:w <CR> <C-o> :!ruby % <CR>
```

this way you can save and execute your file at once within *insertion mode*

Answer (score 0):

In vim:

```
:!ruby %
```

will execute ruby on the current file. Remember to save it first!

Answer (score 0):

If you are the Emacs type you should check out ruby-mode (which IIRC was written by Matz) and inf-ruby. See e.g. http://lathi.net/pages/emacs-ruby

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what OS you're using, so I'm assuming either Linux or Mac-OS.

When you're at a command-line and using vim (not gvim) you can do a <CNTRL>+Z to temporarily halt the editor and return to the command-line. Issue any commands you need, then use "fg" to return to the editor.

There are times I'll use :!ruby % from inside vim (or gvim) but sometimes I need the real command line and if I'm ssh'd into a machine the <CNTRL>+Z trick is nice.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @Simone Carletti. If you are learning the language and want to make sure that methods/classes are doing what you want then you can use `irb`.

There is a gem called `interactive_editor` which enable you to run vim inside `irb` (side-by-side actually). Watch this [Vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/running-vim-within-irb/) for demo.